# jQuery scrolling to a section

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

Why is my *scrolling to a div* not working? Where is the error?

Here is the codepen simulating my code: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/vGdPLB)

```
$(function() {
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
 });
});
```

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use : `$("a[href*='#']").not("a[href='#']")` or `$("a[href*='#']:not([href='#'])")`

```
$(function() {
 $("a[href*='#']").not("a[href='#']").click(function() {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
 });
});
```

Working example :

```js
$(function() {
      $("a[href*='#']").not("a[href='#']").click(function() {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#about, #top  {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#top" id="bt-first">FIRST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" id="bt-about">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section id="top">
  <h2>SECTION X</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <h2>ABOUT</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your `<a>` tags already are using `#{section}` as their `href`, which is going to cause the page to instantly jump to those anchors. You likely need to prevent this behavior when your link is clicked on by using [`e.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) in your function.

You'll also need to adjust your selectors to use quotes to ensure they work properly (the [documentation mentions that it works for quoted or unquoted values](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/), but it generally works better with quotes):

```
// Added quotes to comparison selectors (this is usually necessary)
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(e) {
    // Prevent any default link behavior (may be overkill in this scenario)
    e.preventDefault();
    // Omitted for brevity
});
```

You can see [an updated CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reJRWr).